# place tensorflow.js into a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow.js

I'm looking for the simplest way to translate some vanilla tf.js into a react component.

Here is a React component:

```
class KMeans extends Component {
render() {
      return (
        <div className="KMeansMonitor">
        </div>
      )
  }
}
export default KMeans;
```

and I have an async function to calculate MSE:

```
async function learnLinear(){
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
  model.compile({
   loss: 'meanSquaredError',
   optimizer: 'sgd'
  });

  const xs = tf.tensor2d([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 1]);
  const ys = tf.tensor2d([-3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7], [6, 1]);

  await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 500});

  document.getElementById('output_field').innerText =
   model.predict(tf.tensor2d([10], [1, 1]));
 }
 learnLinear();
```

I would just like to have this vanilla js running in the React component. Any help, as always, is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple. Change `learnLinear` function so it just returns Promise with value and use necessary hooks to wait for data & update state

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

async function learnLinear() {

 const model = tf.sequential();
  const layer = tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]});

  model.add(layer);
  model.compile({
   loss: 'meanSquaredError',
   optimizer: 'sgd'
  });

  const xs = tf.tensor2d([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 1]);
  const ys = tf.tensor2d([-3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7], [6, 1]);

  await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 500});
  const prediction = await model.predict(tf.tensor2d([10], [1, 1]));
  
  return prediction.toString();
}


const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [dots, setDots] = useState(['.']);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let isUnmounted = false;
    let handle = null;
    
    learnLinear()
      .then(result => {
        if(isUnmounted) {
          return;
        }
      console.log(result);
        setValue(result);
      });
      
    const dotsAnimation = () => {
      setDots(dots => {
        const newDots = [...dots, dots[0]];
        
        return newDots.length === 4 ? ['.'] : newDots;
        })
    
      handle = setTimeout(dotsAnimation, 100);
    }
    
    handle = setTimeout(dotsAnimation, 100);
      
    return () => {
      isUnmounted = true;
      clearTimeout(handle);
    }
  }, [])

return <div>
  {value ?  value : 'Predicting value' + dots.join('')}
</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: under model.add, it returns Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): trackerFn(...).makeTensor is not a function

Comment: weird, what browser are you using?